# ¿Cómo obtener fecha máxima de diferentes fechas con mismo ID SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lo que intento realizar es obtener la fecha máxima de diferentes fechas con un mismo ID. Entonces si para ese ID existen registros con una fecha del mismo mes pero con diferencia de días y horas, ¿cómo obtengo el registro de la última hora de ese día y mes?, además ese registro para el mes siguiente tiene el mismo caso.

Un ejemplo, Los datos serían:

```
|------|--------|---------------------|
|  ID  | NOMBRE |        Fecha        |
|------|--------|---------------------|
|  1   |   N1   | 2020-01-01 10:00:00 |
|------|--------|---------------------|
|  1   |   N1   | 2020-01-01 11:00:00 |
|------|--------|---------------------|
|  1   |   N1   | 2020-01-02 10:00:00 |
|------|--------|---------------------|
|  1   |   N1   | 2020-01-02 11:00:00 |
|------|--------|---------------------|
|  1   |   N1   | 2020-02-01 10:00:00 |
|------|--------|---------------------|
|  1   |   N1   | 2020-02-01 11:00:00 |
|------|--------|---------------------|
|  1   |   N1   | 2020-02-02 10:00:00 |
|------|--------|---------------------|
|  1   |   N1   | 2020-02-02 11:00:00 |
|------|--------|---------------------|
```

Lo que se espera obtener:

```
|------|--------|---------------------|
|  ID  | NOMBRE |        Fecha        |
|------|--------|---------------------|
|  1   |   N1   | 2020-01-01 11:00:00 |
|------|--------|---------------------|
|  1   |   N1   | 2020-01-02 11:00:00 |
|------|--------|---------------------|
|  1   |   N1   | 2020-02-01 11:00:00 |
|------|--------|---------------------|
|  1   |   N1   | 2020-02-02 11:00:00 |
|------|--------|---------------------|
```

Answer (score 2):

Con un `group by` lo consigues fácilmente, pero agrupando la fecha como fecha y no como fecha y hora, esto lo conseguimos con un `convert`.

```
select ID, Nombre, convert(varchar, Fecha, 112) as FechaStr, max(Fecha) as Fecha
from tabla
group by ID, Nombre, convert(varchar, Fecha, 112)
```

Si te molesta el campo añadido (`FechaStr`), lo puedes poner en una subconsulta

```
select ID, Nombre, Fecha 
from (
    select ID, Nombre, convert(varchar, Fecha, 112) as FechaStr, max(Fecha) as Fecha
    from tabla
    group by ID, Nombre, convert(varchar, Fecha, 112)
) a
```

Comment: Dejo un poc de ésta respuesta http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/455a54/1 :D